# How to properly write an 'If in' statement for an encoded string?

Tags: python, if-statement, encode

I'm trying to take the string `hello`, encode it into hexadecimal, and then print `success` if the value of `t` is found in the encoded string.

This is what I have currently:

```
import codecs

t='68656c6c6df'
pkts = ("hello")
pkts1 = codecs.encode(b'hello', 'hex_codec')

if "t" in pkts1:
print ('success')
```

Which gives me the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/K/.PyCharmCE2018.1/config/scratches/scratch_1.py", line 8, in <module>
    if "t" in pkts1:
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Comment: Put a little `b` right in front of your literal: `t = b'68646c6f'`, also when you reference `t` below don't put it in quotation marks.

Comment: That did it, thank you.